# Why do we have to malloc in this string function c?

Tags: c, string, memory, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

```
char * concat(const char *s1, const char *s2) {
    char result[70];
    strcpy(result, s1);
    strcat(result, s2);
    return result;
}
int main() {
    char *s1 = "Hello";
    char *s2 = " World!";
    char *s3 = concat(s1, s2);
    printf("%s\n", s3);

    return 0;
}
```

This program just calls the `concat` function which returns a `char *` that is the concat of `s1 and s2`. However, upon compiling, I get the error `address of stack memory associated with local variable 'result' returned`.

So I understand that `result` is a local variable in the concat function, but not really why we have to malloc it. Why doesn't result just get returned with `Hello World` as it's value?

If you consider a program like this:

```
int ret() {

    int a = 4;
    return a;
}
int main() {
    int b = ret();
    printf("%d\n", b); // 4

    return 0;
}
```

there is no error. I don't have to malloc the int. `a` is local, but I still return it and it still works.

I want to know what's the main difference between concat and ret, and why concat **must** dynamically allocate memory. Thank you.

Comment: Would someone care to explain the downvote so I can improve this question?

Comment: *Where* this "Hello world" is supposed to be stored?

Comment: There is a fundamental difference in the way that arrays are handled as arguments/return values.

Comment: `char *` means "pointer to char",  not "block of 70 characters"

Comment: I found the dup... eventually:(

Comment: @MartinJames Well, the OP is claiming that "*I understand that result is a local variable in the concat function*". Which makes it more "unclear" than dup.

Comment: The difference between the two codes is, in other words, the difference between the value type and the reference type. You can return the value as a value type  like [this](http://ideone.com/OmcCRX)

Comment: @EugeneSh.: I disagree with _unclear_. The question was posted because OP does not know about memory layout nor the difference between stack and heap. Therefore, OP would have a hard time deducing the correct wording to search for it. I'd close as _dup_, at most.

Comment: I close it as a dup because I have the hammer - it is faster.

Answer (score 3):

From the C Standard (6.2.4 Storage durations of objects)

> 1 **An object has a storage duration that determines its lifetime.**
>   There are four storage durations: static, thread, **automatic**, and
>   allocated. Allocated storage is described in 7.22.3.
>
> 2 The lifetime of an object is the portion of program execution during
>   which storage is guaranteed to be reserved for it. An object exists,
>   has a constant address,33) and retains its last-stored value
>   throughout its lifetime.34) **If an object is referred to outside of
>   its lifetime, the behavior is undefined. The value of a pointer
>   becomes indeterminate when the object it points to (or just past)
>   reaches the end of its lifetime.**

and

> 6 For such an object that does not have a variable length array type,
>   its lifetime extends from entry into the block with which it is
>   associated until execution of that block ends in any way...

In this function definition

```
char * concat(const char *s1, const char *s2) {
    char result[70];
    strcpy(result, s1);
    strcat(result, s2);
    return result;
}
```

the variable `result` has the automatic storage duration. Its lifetime is ended after exiting the function. So as it is written in the Standard

> If an object is referred to outside of its lifetime, the behavior is
>   undefined.

If to allocate the array dynamically then its lifetime will not end after exiting the function and a pointer that points to it will be valid. You can access the allocated memory outside the function where it was allocated.

As for this function definition

```
int ret() {

    int a = 4;
    return a;
}
```

then the function returns the object itself. If you returned the object indirectly through a pointer like this

```
int * ret() {

    int a = 4;
    return &a;
}
```

then you had the same problem as with the first program that is the program will have undefined behavior if you try to access the variable `a` using the returned pointer.

Take into account that functions can return an object of the type `int` but they can not return an array.

Answer (score 0):

```
char * concat(const char *s1, const char *s2) {
    char result[70];
    strcpy(result, s1);
    strcat(result, s2);
    return result;
}
```

In your function, the result array is freed after the function call, so 
`char *s3 = concat(s1, s2);` pointer s3 is pointing to an invalid address.

Answer (score 0):

There are ways to make this function work without dynamic memory allocations. For example, you can ditch all hopes if being multi-threading compatible and declare a static variable inside the function. Illustration:

```
char* concat() {
    static char result[70];
    // ... rest of the code
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Returning a primitive like an `int` and returning a string is fundamentally different in C. A string is not a primitive object and is actually a character array. Just like how you cannot declare an array in a function locally, then return that array, you cannot simply return the string. The compiler does not throw an error, but instead a warning, because usually, the stack frame where the contents of `result` is stored is not cleared when the function returns, so for a short time after exiting the function, you **MIGHT** be still able to the pointer returned, but don't count on it.

The fundamental difference here is that `malloc` will allocate space on the heap, which will not be overwritten unless explicitly told otherwise, whereas simply declaring an array in a function does not guarantee that the space the array occupies will still be accessible / readable after the exit of the function (hence a local variable).

Comment: It is a classical example of the UB.

Comment: UB being undefined behaviour?

Comment: Yo my friend. The Undefined Behaviour

Comment: Your 'because usually...' is very wrong. This is not while compiler doesn't give an error.